# Calling Multiple Functions Using Argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, command-line, argparse

Im trying to call various functions using argparse, where each functions intakes a file from the command line, using sub-command in argparse.

Ive tried using dictionary keys mapping to the various functions, and using sub-command options in argparse, but i am stuck.

```py
def weekly_top50_brownsugar_titles(bc_file=None):
    in takes csv file and uses pandas to filter and export
    returns output in folder

def weekly_top50courttv_titles(court_file=None):
    intakes csv file
    . ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description='Automated Process To Do Reports. '
                    'Reports Include: Weekly Top 50 Titles Report,'
                    'Monthly Top Titles Report,'
                    'Roku And Stripe Subscriber Metrics Gathering.')
      args, sub_args = parser.parse_known_args()

      if args.function == weekly_top50_brownsugar_titles:
      parser_a = ArgumentParser()
      parser_a.add_argument('-a','--a')
```

but this does not work. i am confused on where to go from here.

Comment: Take a look at the `nargs` parameter in [the `argparse` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#example)

Comment: Where did you define `parser`?  Show us you know how to create a parser that can set one or more string attributes.  Running a function based on the parsed values comes later, and can be done in various ways.  For a start do the obvious.

Comment: Don't say `this does not work`.  Show the error or what is wrong.  Similarly don't just say you tried this or that; show it.  We like to help you debug code, we are less inclined to write a lot of new code for you.